# node_modules resolution details

Tags: node.js, npm

With the following lookup algorithm in mind:
https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders

Say we have this in package.json:

```
"dependencies":{
  "foo":"latest",
  "bar":"latest",
  "baz":"latest"
}
```

given the above algorithm (read the link), I believe it is absolutely true, that in our project'ss primary node_modules folder, we must have at least 3 folders:

```
node_modules/
    foo/
    bar/
    baz/
```

what confused me though, is that I swear I have seen case where foo/bar/baz was missing, and the modules still resolved with require. Although maybe I was imagining things.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to run `npm install` most of time if you have updated your packages.json file